# Crystal 4 Pins SMD footprint

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, crystal, footprint

I'm designing PCB that includes [24MHz SMD 4 pins crystal](https://abracon.com/AIGcrystals/ABM10AIG.pdf).

According to my understanding, the crystal package marking is for Pin number 4.

I wonder, how should I indicate in the PCB this pin? Should I put a circle near this pin as I do to any SMD to indicate Pin #1?
actually, I did it but I'm not sure about it.

Is there any standard or marking for this situation?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Because the electrical orientation of the crystal crystal does not matter and package has 180° symmetry, it doesn't really matter which way round the crystal is mounted.

If you place a mark on the PCB, this will generally be assumed to correspond to pin 1 unless the device has an obvious mark on a different pin.  In the case of the crystal, which is marked only by a different contact shape on the bottom, this may not be obvious to the manufacturer.  If the orientation actually mattered, as it does for most components, you would want to include a detailed assembly specification that cleared up any ambiguities.